# text-overflow inheriting fonts from pseudo elements in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

I've encountered a weird bug reproducible in IE9 where the `text-overflow` ellipsis is inheriting the font styles of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c7zgD/7/

It wouldn't be a massive problem, except in my case I'm using an icon font to prefix some text and so the ellipsis is coming out as missing glyphs.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Oddly enough, Chrome 27 seems to give the monospace font to the ellipsis but not the maroon color.

Comment: In Chrome 28 the ellipsis doesn't inherit anything. Hm, and I can't get it to do this in IE 7, 8, 9 or 10 either. What OS are you on?

Comment: I discovered the problem on a Windows 7 VM

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution in the past... Add an empty char with before:

```
.btn:before {
    content: '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tagliala/TtbuG/10/